# Difference between DSPIC33 and PIC24 programming?

Tags: microcontroller

Is there any difference between the syntax of DSPIC33 and PIC 24? I need to program a PIC33, will learning how to program in PIC24 help Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The only real difference is that dsPIC33 has a few extra instructions/features for DSP.

In practice there is no difference in programming for these processor families, unless you are using the special DSP-optimized features of the dsPIC.

Comment: Ah right, thanks! I was planning on using the FFT features of the dsPIC